# Do I need to close connection if SqlConnection.ExecuteReader returns null?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server

Rather straightforward question:

If I use an `SqlConnection.ExecuteReader` to execute a stored procedure and return some rows, if it returns `null` do I have to close the connection?

Also, if the answer is "no I don't have to close the connection," what would happen if I do?

Comment: The SqlConnection has been created previously, and SqlDataReader does not manager the connection lifetime (code *must* dispose the SqlDataReader before using the connection for other things, but that isn't to change the connection state). Btw: how does SqlDataReader "return null"?

Comment: Yes, I was slightly confused, I reworded the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any resource that is opened needs to be closed (when you are completely done using it). You should use the [try-catch-finally](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dszsf989.aspx) construct and put the clean up code in the finally just in case an exception occurs. Otherwise the reference to the resource will become orphaned and Garbage Collection will not be able to get rid of it (well, until the App Domain is recycled). You should also look into the `using` statement as shown in the C# example on the [SqlConnection.Open](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.open.aspx) MSDN page.

**EDIT** (additional info based on comment discussion on another answer):
The "resources" in question that can become orphaned are:

- memory
- file handles
- connections to a database (e.g. SQL Server)
- etc

When references to these resources are orphaned, they will remain in use by .Net and result in gobbling up memory or, in the specific case noted in the comments, using up all available connections to SQL Server.

Answer (score 2):

if you are done work on the server, yes, if you want to submit another request than no, this is irrelevant from what SqlDataReader returns, sometimes to optimize work on server, you might create a class that is constantly connected to the sql server and you just submit tasks to it.

on request start, open the connection
....
perform tasks on sql server
...
on connection end close the connection

the best place to do this is global.asax file

regarding what will happen if you close the connection, SqlDataReader works on an open connection, if you close the connection and execute the reader again you get an exception

Comment: Please explain what you mean for _constantly connected to the server_ because in a server environment having a connection always connected is a big no no.

Comment: if you need to perform many actions on a sql server in one request, just open 1 connection on start, and keep it open, then close it on request end

Comment: Now it is more clear and I can agree with you. The key is _one request that performs multiple actions_. I suggest to add that at your answer

Comment: The current exiting architecture I'm working with opens a new connection for each request. So I have to deal.

Comment: I revised the question to be more accurate.

Comment: This is strange, as I'm going through the code base, it was designed such that all of the `close()` calls are wrapped inside an `if (sqlDataReader != null)`, and it's always worked fine.

Comment: @m-theory: define "worked fine" ;-). If the SqlConnection is not properly closed, you won't see an exception. However, it will slowly chew up resources due to the memory not being eligible to be GCed (as I noted in my answer). If anything, the code should have been `if (SqlConnection != null)`.

Comment: @srutzky - right, but this app has been live for a few years and never did we have an issue. We recently made some changes, and it turns out a call to `close()` was missed on a new DB call, and within a day we had a max pool size reached in IIS

Comment: @m-theory: yes, that is _exactly_ what I am referring to when I say that resources need to be closed or else they will chew up other resources (memory, file handles, connections, etc). I was also saying that checking SqlDataReader is not the best test for SqlConnection since it could lead to SqlDataReader being null while the SqlConnection has been opened and hence won't be closed. It could be that your app has been very slowly keeping connections open, but so few that you haven't noticed.